# Python library azureml-sdk[databricks] downgrades other needed libraries on Databricks cluster

Tags: python-3.x, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-machine-learning-service

Azure Machine Learning python package occasionally returns dependency errors on Databricks.  I am using Databricks runtime 6.0 (non-ML) with `azureml-sdk[databricks]` PyPi package.  In particular, the `cryptography` and `pyopenssl` packages are downgraded from 2.6.1 and 19.0.0 to 1.5 and 16.0.0 when `azureml-sdk[databricks]` is installed.  Installing another package that has the requirement `pyopenssl>=18.0.0` succeeds, as does installing `cryptography==2.6.1` and `pyopenssl==19.0.0` separately on the Databricks cluster, but sometimes during the job errors like this appear:

```
Failure while loading azureml_run_type_providers. Failed to load entrypoint hyperdrive = azureml.train.hyperdrive:HyperDriveRun._from_run_dto with exception (cryptography 1.5 (/databricks/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('cryptography>=2.3'), {'pyopenssl'}).
Failure while loading azureml_run_type_providers. Failed to load entrypoint azureml.PipelineRun = azureml.pipeline.core.run:PipelineRun._from_dto with exception (cryptography 1.5 (/databricks/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('cryptography>=2.3'), {'pyopenssl'}).
Failure while loading azureml_run_type_providers. Failed to load entrypoint azureml.ReusedStepRun = azureml.pipeline.core.run:StepRun._from_reused_dto with exception (cryptography 1.5 (/databricks/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('cryptography>=2.3'), {'pyopenssl'}).
Failure while loading azureml_run_type_providers. Failed to load entrypoint azureml.StepRun = azureml.pipeline.core.run:StepRun._from_dto with exception (cryptography 1.5 (/databricks/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('cryptography>=2.3'), {'pyopenssl'}).
Failure while loading azureml_run_type_providers. Failed to load entrypoint azureml.scriptrun = azureml.core.script_run:ScriptRun._from_run_dto with exception (cryptography 1.5 (/databricks/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('cryptography>=2.3'), {'pyopenssl'}).
From cffi callback <function _verify_callback at 0x7f587ef90268>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 309, in wrapper
    _lib.X509_up_ref(x509)
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_up_ref'
From cffi callback <function _verify_callback at 0x7f587ef90d08>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 309, in wrapper
    _lib.X509_up_ref(x509)
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_up_ref'
From cffi callback <function _verify_callback at 0x7f587dc1d950>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 309, in wrapper
    _lib.X509_up_ref(x509)
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_up_ref'
From cffi callback <function _verify_callback at 0x7f587dc25268>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 309, in wrapper
    _lib.X509_up_ref(x509)
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_up_ref'

SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='southcentralus.experiments.azureml.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /discovery (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))
```

This does not happen every time the job is run.  I tried switching the order that packages are installed, but it still happens intermittently.  Is there a reason for `azureml-sdk[databricks]` to require a lower version of `cryptography` and `pyopenssl` than a cluster without it, or with `azureml-sdk`?  What can I do to ensure dependencies are all satisfied?